# BSOD whea during Virtualbox installation

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, bsod

With Windows 7 or Windows 10 64-bit, I always had Virtualbox installed on this computer.
A few weeks ago, I format and reinstalled Windows 10 64-bit from scratch (the previous Windows 10 installation was an update from Windows 7).

Yesterday, I wanted to install Virtualbox again, but during the installation, and it seems close to the end of the installation, the PC crashes with a BSOD error (WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE ERROR).

I opened the MEMORY.DMP with Windbg and this is the result after an !analyze -v : http://pastebin.com/LDXnhbbp

I searched on the Internet and it seems that the CPU can be the problem : for information, I never had BSOD before, and I play many games.
I downloaded the Intel CPU Identification utility, and it seems that my processor was overclocked by the Intel Turbo technology : I disabled it in the BIOS, but the problem is still there.

My drivers are up-to-date with the [Snappy drivers](https://sdi-tool.org/) tools.

Is there any fix to this problem?

Comment: run **!errrec ffffe0014e2fa028** to see more details.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution : disabling Intel Virtualization Technology in the BIOS.
After that, I could installed VirtualBox with no problem.

I enabled again the turbo options and the Virtualization technology in the BIOS in order to see if it's okay when I will running VMs.